# Invoke a function inside condition

Tags: reactjs

I want to dispatch an action in reactjs. 
I dispatch using useEffect():

```js
useEffect(() => {
  addData({
    ...cars[0],
  });
}, [var]);
```

My dispatch looks like:

```js
const addData = payload => {
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
  return dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_SOMETHING' });
};
```

Also, i have a condition:

```js
  const condition = a.length === b.length;
```

And i want to dispatch using:

```js
if (condition === true) {  //Only in this case to dispatch
  const addData = payload => {
    dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
    return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING' });
  };
}
```

I want to dispatch only when: `condition === true`, but now `addData` is inside of the block scope of `if`, and i can't do what i want. How to achieve my target?

Comment: Declaring a function definition and invoking it aren't the same thing. What, and where, are `a` and `b`? Where is the conditional test? Please provide complete component code.

Comment: Why do you have `var` in your `useEffect` dependencies? Could you show the full component so we can get more context?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is if you wrap the function declaration inside an `if` statement block, it will be scoped to that block.

What you're actually looking to do is declare the function and then wrap the function call in an `if` statement block.

You should implement it like this:

```
// Take the condition out here
const addData = payload => { 
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
  return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING' });
};

useEffect(() => {
  // Instead, use the condition here
  if (a.length === b.length) {
    addData({ ...cars[0] });
  }
}, [a, b]);
```

**Another Recommendation:**

You shouldn't really be dispatching twice in your `addData` function.

```
const addData = payload => { 
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
  return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING' });
};
```

Should really be:

```
const addData = payload => { 
  return dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
};
```

If multiple dispatches were intentional, then it'd be better to handle them on the `reducer` side.

Comment: your code is ok, but the issue in useEffect, because, on the first render the results of `a.length`, and `b.length` are how i expect, but at the second render i get expected value only for `a`, not for `b`, and this is why at the second render i dispatch, even it does not fit  the condition.

Comment: this is why i wanted to do my condition outside useEffect, because there i get expected values

Comment: I tried: 
const addData = payload => {
if(condition === true) {
  dispatch({ type: 'ADD_SOMETHING', payload });
  return dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_SOMETHING' });
}};  but  also i get different values for variables from condition. What could be the issue?  @Barry Michael Doyle

Comment: Did you try my updated answer yet? And if that didn't work, are you going to show us your full component so we can actually see the full picture (not in isolation). I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Asking That sounds like an issue with whatever `b` is if its length isn't what you're expecting it to be. You can also use more than one effect, one "onMount" effect to do the comparison and dispatch and a second to simply dispatch when either of `a` or `b` update.  And yes, please update question with your code so it is clearer what you're asking to do.